# PagingAndSortingRepository query to returns entities that match a set of entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA with Hibernate. I have this entity:

```
package com.test.model.entity;

@Entity
public class Article {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = DETACH)
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

Can I do something like that to get all the articles that have at least one tag matching in the given set?

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Article, Long> {

    Page<Article> findAllByTags(Set<Tag> tags, Pageable pageabled);
}
```

Otherwise, how can I get this using pagination?

In alternative, can I use `@Query` and still keep the pagination?

**UPDATE**

To me Robert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401140/1983997) returns

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 71 [SELECT a FROM com.test.model.entity.Article a WHERE a.tags = ANY (:tagsToContain)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `@Query` and `Pageable`. Try:

```
@Query("select a from Article a where a.tags = any (:tagsToContain)")
Page<Article> findAllByTags(Set<Tag> tagsToContain, Pageable pageabled);
```